# Delay between animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I'm trying to add a delay at the beginning of each set of animations. The animation works fine but when I add .delay(5000) before .animate nothing works.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    -->add .delay here <---

    $("#hand").animate({left:'-=300px'},1500 );
    $("#hand").animate({left:'+=300px'},1000 );

    -->add .delay here <---

    $("#hand").animate({left:'-=300px'},1500  );
    $("#hand").animate({left:'+=300px'},1000 );

    $("#hand").animate({left:'-=300px'},1500  );
    $("#hand").animate({left:'+=300px'},1000 );

    });
```

Is there one set code to use for the same function here? I need it to animate infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You <strike>have to</strike> can use chaining for the animation / delay calls - example:

```
$("#hand").animate({left:'-=300px'},1500)
          .delay(5000)
          .animate({left:'+=300px'},1500);
```

Note that the `animate()` call itself is non-blocking so you have to accommodate for that in the `delay()` call or move the code to the completion handler instead.
See this [working JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrokenGlass/a7jhh/1/).

To make this run "forever" you can just wrap it into `setInterval()`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#hand").animate({ left: '-=300px'}, 1500)
              .delay(5000)
              .animate({left: '+=300px'}, 1000);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: It does actually [work without chaining](http://jsfiddle.net/MnFfa/), but of course chaining is much nicer.

Comment: -1 because patrick is right; chaining is convenient but repeated, non-chained calls to `animate` queue up just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a recursive function call to make your animation loop infinitely.

```
function recursive_animation() {
    $("#hand").delay( 3000 )
        .animate({left:'-=300px'},1500 )
        .animate({left:'+=300px'},1000, recursive_animation );
}

recursive_animation();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/j3LLe/

Comment: With this solution, one day, you will come to _stack overflow_ ;)